# Cocos2d libraries import messed up after using SlidingMenuGrid.mm?

Tags: iphone, menu, cocos2d-iphone

I've been using the SlidingMenuGrid.mm presented by (http://brandonreynolds.com/blog/2011/01/09/cocos2d-sliding-menu-grid/) and discussed in (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12477). It worked great on game project I started doing from scratch.

Unfortunately, I then tried to add it to an existing source code, from the (http://www.apress.com/9781430233039) book and did not work. The first problem is that in CCMeu.h the following enumeration were not declared, so I had to add them:

```
typedef enum  {
    kCCMenuStateWaiting,
    kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch
} tCCMenuState;

enum {
    //* priority used by the menu for the touches
    kCCMenuTouchPriority = -128,

    //* priority used by the menu for the mouse
    kCCMenuMousePriority = -128,
};
```

Then, the compilation errors got reduced and I was left with the following error:

```
/Classes/SlidingMenuGrid.mm:117: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'
```

Is weird, as also the parent class returns void and even more, the same library inserted in the other project works fine and does not complain (the code is the same).

Here is line 117 of SlidingMenuGrid.mm for reference:

```
-(void) addChild:(CCMenuItem*)child z:(int)z tag:(int)aTag
{
    return [super addChild:child z:z tag:aTag];
}
```

I thought the problem might have to do with the version of cocos2d included by the source code of the example file. Hence I removed the "CocosDenshion" "Cocos2d" "cocoslive" and "FontLabel" folders and replaced them with the one with my other project. Unfortunately now I get 32 compilation errors.. not one :).. the first one is

/Classes/GameScene.h:36: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CCLabel'

Which looks to me like I messed up even more with the libraries. I then cleaned the project and all the targets and recompiled but did not change. I tried few more times and here I am posting this message.. I am a bit stuck.. sorry..

Thanks for reading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the "return" here to fix the error:

```
-(void) addChild:(CCMenuItem*)child z:(int)z tag:(int)aTag
{
   [super addChild:child z:z tag:aTag];
}
```

The issues aren't just cocos2d version differences but also Compiler settings. In particular if a project uses Apple LLVM Compiler x.x you get more accurate (and more) warnings and errors which is generally a good thing to have.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, It was not due to this at the end.. there was a problem with CCLabel not being recognized (I had to replace CCLabel with CCLabelTTF). I did so also when I tried to use some of your code example within my excercises. I do not know if it is because of the compilers or not. I was not aware of that option and hence had subsituted the code. Shall I try? By the way, I wanted to thank you for the great book you wrote, I read it all and am very glad for the amount of material you published with it.